# Media Controls in Picture in Picture ExoPlayer

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I am using ExoPlayer to play my streams. I have implemented Picture in Picture which works pretty good but i haven't been able to implement play, pause controls on PiP window until now. I know that by defaul Exoplayer + Picture in Picture does not give us the Picture in Picture media controls we see in the Youtube player for instance.

Anyway i searched a lot about this issue, and found out a code that may help me but the problem is that the code is in Kotlin and i am using Java, as a beginner i wasn't able to find the alternative code for Java to make it work.

This is the recommendation i got:

```
    val mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, packageName)
val mediaSessionConnector = MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession)
mediaSessionConnector.setPlayer(player, null)
mediaSession.isActive = true
```

I know that i should implement it onStart() after handling Exoplayer. I thinked about converting my project in Kotlin but as a beginner i would like to focus in Java and instead find a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Android will show media controls in Picture-in-picture mode automatically if there is an active media session for the app.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

Also, the code you posted belongs to the media session extension library for exoplayer, so you need to add it to your build.gradle

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/mediasession